# Error: can't get a valid version for repositories <package>. Try changing the version constraint in Chart.yaml

Tags: helm

When I run `helm dependency build` I get

> Error: can't get a valid version for repositories ingress-nginx. Try changing the version constraint in Chart.yaml

I've tried all kinds of things the version,

```
1.x.x
~1
^1
```

Everything generates that error. This the relevant part of my Chart.yaml

```
- name: ingress-nginx
    repository: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
    version: 1.x.x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## App Version vs Chart Version

There are two pieces of software in play with different version numbers,

- [nginx upstream]([https://github.com/nginx/nginx]](https://github.com/nginx/nginx%5D) which in this example is currently at 1.23.4
- [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx.git) which is a chart that uses nginx and that chart is currently at 4.6.0

The helm dependency `version` field is for the version of the chart. Not the upstream software being packaged.